# Legs sweating during exercise

Tags: running, long-distance-running, sweat

I was working out yesterday, I have recently increased the pace at which I run at yesterday, for the first time my legs were sweating more than my upper body, usually it is my upper body that does the sweating, but for some reason my thighs were sweating rigorously. This has never happened before, could someone explain why we sweat more in some places than in others? why it isn't all round? and perhaps explain why that happened yesterday? it was only a treadmill workout.

Comment: You've never sweated on your thighs before?

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD no I haven't :S not even when I'm squatting or anything.

Comment: Maybe you were wearing sweats and not shorts ?

Comment: @brentwpeterson I was wearing trackies... :\ it does happen a lot more now though...like a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of some common reasons that lead to excessive sweating at various sites of the body:

Low blood sugar levels, 
Metabolism related issues, 
Hyperthyroidism, 
Any disorder of the nerves or injury to the spinal cord, 
Stress or paranoia, 
Panic or anxiety attacks, 
Disease or infection of the liver, 
Hot flashes (especially in post menopausal women), 
Lymphoma,
Parasitic infection,
Diseases or disorders of the deeper dermal layer such as vitiligo,
Side effects of certain medications - especially those administered for treating ,cancers, AIDS and also s,ome antibiotics and paracetamols,
Heart disease,
Diabetes Mellitus,